# simple android ui emulator for showing what xml would look like

Tags: android, xml

i was wondering if there is any software that someone wrote for
showing what an .xml file would look like, just for experimenting UI while not having access to an android IDE.. i looked online but could find anything like that, so is there anybody out there who does know?

Answer (score 0):

This is built into both Android Studio and the Eclipse IDE.  If you bring up an XML file in the Layout editor, there is a "design" tab that will show you a rendering of how your layout will look.

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't another way to preview this without using the IDE.